# Using PHP To Print Elements From MySQL Database As Links To Respective Image

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Say I have a MySQL database structured like this:

```
id    name    png
1     Bob     img1
2     Jim     img2
.      .       .
.      .       .
.      .       .
```

where the png column store images as the BLOB datatype.

What I would like to do is loop through the database and print out all of the contents in the "name" field on a page where each name link provides a link to the respective image. Any feedback would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the images are only saved as a BLOB in the database, you'll have to write a second script that fetches an image from the database and sends it to the client. You can then output links to this script (with a GET parameter so the correct image is displayed).

If the images are very small, I think you could also do it with the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (you'd have to output the BLOB content of every image encoded as base64 inside the `href` of the link).

Comment: Or you could just save the images in the database as base64 =)

Comment: @RobinJ: base64 has about 33% overhead compared to the original data, so it will take up a lot of storage space unnecessarily. Also, a rule of thumb is to always store data in databases in their most pure and natural form, in this case the binary representation of the image file.